# Testing if an event has been triggered in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, jquery-events

How do you test if an event has been fired in Jasmine without `jquery-jasmine`?

I'm working on a project where we don't use jQuery (wohoo), and I'm trying to write a unit test for my menu triggering function. It works like this:

- You click a button
- My testable component then runs `document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('menu.toggle'))`
- I want to test that the component indeed dispatched the custom event.

How do I test this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Played around a bit and found a solution that worked well:

```
import triggerEvent from 'trigger-event';
import component from './components/site-menu';

describe('triggering menu button', () => {
  let menuToggleSpy;
  beforeEach(() => {
    menuToggleSpy = jasmine.createSpy('event');
    component();
  });

  it('dispatches menu.toggle event', () => {
    document.addEventListener('menu.toggle', menuToggleSpy);

    const $trigger = document.querySelector('.js-trigger-main-menu');
    triggerEvent($trigger, 'click');

    expect(menuToggleSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Basically create a new spy called 'event', adding it as a event handler for my event, and then verifying it's been called.

If there are better ways to do this, I'll be more than happy to accept a different answer.

Comment: Where is `menuToggleSpy` defined here? I'm getting a "can't find variable" error.

Comment: Hmmm... the event under test is "menu.toggle", I don't see clearly how "createSpy('event')" can help to inspect the actual "menu.toggle" event

Comment: @adamdport - It's specified on the first line in the `describe` block.

@zameb - I add the spy as an event handler for the "menu.toggle" event on the first line of the actual test.